# How to get list of checkmark-ed rows in tableview Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have enable multi row selection and am able to add checkmarks as the user touches the specific cell(s). Now at the end, I want to see which rows were selection and perform actions depending on the row numbers. How can I get those row details / numbers? thanks!

code used to select/ deselect rows:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        main_table.reloadData()
        self.main_table.allowsMultipleSelection = true
        self.main_table.allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing = true
    }
```

and then in cell controller:

```
 override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
        accessoryType = selected ? UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.checkmark : UITableViewCell.AccessoryType.none
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all, avoid using *underscore(`_`) notation* to declare the variables in *Swift*. Instead use *camel casing*.

```
@IBOutlet weak var mainTable: UITableView!
```

Next, to get just the `rows` of the selected `indexPaths` in the `tableView`, use **`indexPathsForSelectedRows`** and **`map(_:)`** like so,

```
if let selectedRows = self.tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map({ $0.row }) {
    print(selectedRows)
}
```

Since `indexPathsForSelectedRows` returns an `Optional` `array` of `IndexPath`, you need to unwrap it to get the values.

Answer (score 0):

```
self.main_table.indexPathsForSelectedRows
```

[indexPathsForSelectedRows](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitableview/1614864-indexpathsforselectedrows)

To get just the rows out of that:

```
let rows = self.main_table.indexPathsForSelectedRows.map { $0.row }
```

Comment: I put that statement in a print block and got: Optional([[0, 0], [0, 1], [0, 2]]) . How can I get just the rows? I looked on the link couldn't find anything

Comment: To get just the rows, you can run that through a map: `let rows = self.main_table.indexPathsForSelectedRows?.map { $0.row }`

Answer (score -1):

@pradaclawed. While you selecting `Cell` on `didselect`method you can add `indexpath.row` or selected row data in array and remove when `deselect`. Now you can work on selected `cell` data.